# timer_list driver upgrade from Linux Kernel 4.2 to 5.4. Linux 5.4 has removed timer_list.data which the driver depends on

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers

I'm upgrading a Linux kernel driver from 4.2 to 5.4 and it uses the `timer_list` struct.
The driver passes the main `typedef struct` that timer resides in as an `unsigned long` via the `timer_list.data` element in order to pass the `typedef` between timers.

Given that in 5.4 there is no longer a `timer_list.data` element what is the best way to pass the typedef struct in the new `timer_list` with the `timer_setup` & `add_timer` upgrade to the Linux kernel

So basically to outline the changes I'm talking about

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/include/linux/timer.h#L20
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.122/source/include/linux/timer.h#L18

timer_list driver upgrade from Linux Kernel 4.2 to 5.4. Linux 5.4 has removed `timer_list.data` which the driver deepened on which was an `unsigned long`

I apologize head of time if there any errors in what I have said I am new to C and the linux kernel but not software development or Linux

Comment: "a linux driver" ?  Which one ? some out-of-tree driver ? some code available on some github ?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/quantgeek/mpss-modules

Comment: Has the job of adapting already started but not completed ? does not work ? I am confused reading the code since linvcons.c (line 153) apparently shows some attempt of adaptation to new way, while micscif_rma_dma.c (line 842) still uses the old setup_timer way.

Comment: That is the source code I'm basing my modified code on. Whoops I just realized you wanted the code I'm working on this is the branch I just made public https://github.com/charlieporth1/mpss-modules. I think whats going on is the object the timer is referring is different than the og I think this because of it being a different long